# Detener script si no coinside con condicional php

Tags: php

tengo un script que detecta cuando

```
$usuario_modo = 1
```

y lo que hago es encerrar todo mi codigo en una codicional if para poder mostrarlo, lo que deseo es que por ejemplo si `$usuario_modo !==1` entonces mostrar un mensaje y detener la lectura del archivo php

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que entiendo, tú código es así:

```
<?php

if($usuario_modo == 1){
   ...
}
```

En ese caso, sólo debes hacer lo que comentas que quieres hacer: mostrar un mensaje y parar el código:

```
<?php

if($usuario_modo == 1){
   ...
}
else{
   //die('tu mensaje);
}
```

El cómo lo hagas ya es otra cosa. Ignoro si este archivo tiene código HTML a continuación o si lo llamas a través de un *include*, *require*. En función de cómo se hiciese cambiaría la manera de trabajar con el flujo de código y de mostrar ese mensaje.